# How to use jumplist's <C-i> which is seen as a <Tab>?

Tags: key-bindings, jumplist

On vim's help `:help jumplist` I can read:

> Jumps are remembered in a jump list.  With the `CTRL-O` and `CTRL-I` command you
>   can go to cursor positions before older jumps, and back again.  Thus you can
>   move up and down the list.

However, on my terminal `mintty`, Vim makes no differences between <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>.

I am wondering what is the magic to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> on Vim?

Comment: [This answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3570/6698) by Gilles (a well-known Unix user) clarifies why `TAB` and `CTRL-I` are equivalent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> *is* Tab (`I` is character code 73 and control subtracts 64; this leaves us with 9, which is TAB).

Every vim install I've tried this on (including `gvim`) maps this to `<tab>` - even `:help <ctrl-i>` shows us that the feature you want is actually also bound to `<tab>`.

From my testing, it works fine on any vim install that doesn't map `<tab>` to anything else. Use `:map <tab>` to check if you've got any mappings set up for that key.

Comment: Well yes, I have remapped my `<Tab>` :)

Comment: For reference. To unmap tab, use `:unmap <Tab>`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is doable in mintty, but I have a workaround for iTerm on Mac OS and the same would work for alacritty which is cross platform.

In vim I have this mapping

```
nnoremap <C-n>i <C-i>
```

In teminal preferences I have set up ^i to send hex codes "0xe 0x69" to the shell.

For alacritty you need to add this to the key mapping section of your alacritty.xml

```
- { key: I,        mods: Control, chars:  "\x0e\x69"                       }
```