# How to prevent Vim from making a flashy screen effect when pressing `ESC` or `^[` in normal mode?

Tags: terminal, insert-mode, normal-mode

I often press `ESC`/`^[` to ensure that I've left insert mode and entered normal mode. However, if I'm already in normal mode, Vim displays an annoying flashy screen effect:

[image]

How can I prevent Vim from making this flashy screen effect, when pressing `ESC`/`^[` in normal mode?

Bonus: I guess it has no effect of pressing `ESC`/`^[` in normal mode, other than cancelling the current command e.g. `d`, so why does Vim makes this flashy screen effect?

Comment: You can also often configure how bells work in your terninal emulator (sound, flash, nothing, etc.)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - yeah, I’ve disabled the sound in Terminal on macOS, but this doesn’t stop Vim from making flashy screen.

Answer (score 3):

That's a bell ([a visual bell](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27visualbell%27)). You can turn off bells for Esc in normal mode using [`belloff`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27belloff%27):

```
                        *'belloff'* *'bo'*
'belloff' 'bo'      string  (default "")
            global
    Specifies for which events the bell will not be rung. It is a comma
    separated list of items. For each item that is present, the bell
    will be silenced. This is most useful to specify specific events in
    insert mode to be silenced.

    item        meaning when present    ~
    all     All events.
    [...]
    esc     hitting <Esc> in |Normal-mode|.
```

So:

```
set belloff=esc
```

Comment: Does `set belloff=esc` both cover `ESC` and `^[` (`Ctrl-[`), because I most often use the latter form to escape insert mode (if so, why?). Can you say why anyone would want this bell in normal mode?

Comment: Ctrl-[ is Esc, so yes. Presumably because someone pressing Esc in normal mode is usually trying to get into normal mode already, this tells you when you have reached normal mode and can start a command. (See also, [original vi's help for Esc](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/vi.html).)

Comment: Sorry, if this is too off-topic, but where do you see that `Ctrl-[` is `ESC`? But will pressing `ESC` not always get you into normal mode? Could there be a situation, where I needed to press `ESC` multiple times to get into normal mode?

Comment: @Shuzheng https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3570/205. Say you've used [Ctrl-R `=` in insert mode](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R_%3D), you'll need two Esc to get back to normal mode.

Comment: @Shuzheng bestasciitable.com made by a former mod here