# system function puts extra characters onto stdout

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I just updated to the latest vim (`git fetch && git merge origin/master` followed by building and installing to `/usr/local/...`).  Everything is great except with a little extra stuff I added to my `.vimrc` file to add the location of C++ compiler and add it to `path` so that opening system include files work.  This is the couple of lines that makes this happen:

```
let gppver=system('g++ --version | perl -ne ''/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ && print $1''')
execute 'set path+=/usr/include/c++/' . g:gppver
```

After some trial and error, I've finally discovered that it's the use of `system()`.  I don't understand why.  When that line executes, actually, at the moment that line is commented and I have this because I thought it was my command, `let gppver = system('ls')`.  Even that simple line results in this being echoed to the stdout during startup:

```
[>4;m[>4;2m
```

It doesn't show well in the post, but it's `^[>4;m^[>4;m` or ESC+[ ....  Where is this coming from?  Prior to doing the git fetch and merge, I was running 8.2. I forget which.  However, I hadn't updated at work since March (or earlier).  Looking at the git log, the latest node on master is the tag `8.2.1959`.  Some pointers on why these extra characters are showing would be greatly appreciated.  Just verified to ensure it really is that function, with every other line commented in my `.vimrc` file but `let gppver = system('ls')`, the extra characters are printed.

Comment: Perhaps not a direct answer... but see [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/27400/18609) for more details on the `^[[>4;2m` sequence, it's related to the *modifyOtherKeys* feature of xterm. This feature was introduced in Vim 8.1.2134 and enabled by default in Vim 8.1.2194. See the full answer for more details and possible workarounds.

Comment: @filbranden thank you.  That was indeed the issue.  I may have read for weeks before stumbling on that one.

Comment: Please write a self-answer to indicate which solution worked for you. (Or let us know if you think it would be OK to mark this question as a duplicate of that one.)

Comment: There may be a way to delay this so it doesnt happen at startup, or otherwise run the command in a way that won’t interfere with stdout

Comment: @filbranden although the symptoms were different, I would say that the question/answer you linked are the answer for this question.  I likely saw the issue *only when* using the `system()` function in script because I usually use gvim and not vim.  while troubleshooting, I did see the "strange" characters in the status line as that person mentioned when I tested stuff using just vim.