# escape sequences showing up within vi

Tags: escape

When I am working in vi there pop up things that look like uninterpreted escape sequences. They come for example when I type <kbd>i</kbd> to enter insert mode, or <kbd>ESC</kbd> to leave it

Example, triggered by typing <kbd>i</kbd> immediately followed by <kbd>ESC</kbd>:
`[>4;m[>4;2m`

Version:

```
vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Apr 15 2020 06:40:31)
Included patches: 1-2269
```

This has begun a couple of weeks ago, I suspect it comes from patching the Ubuntu operating system. I can clean them with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (redraw screen) but they restart popping up as soon as I resume typing.

Guessing that the sequences might try to switch colors, I already applied all the known tricks to disable colors, it makes no difference. The version installed does not even support the `syntax on/off` (which I find no hardship :) )

Here's my `.vimrc`:

```
set nohlsearch
set t_Co=0
highlight LineNr NONE
hi CursorLine NONE
hi Normal cterm=none ctermfg=none ctermbg=none
```

Comment: Your TERM is most probably wrong.  You can try to fix it, or you can try to clear the terminal options `t_TE` and `t_TI`.  See this answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/27400/17449

Comment: extended .vimrc and it is ok now. Thanks! I wonder what caused it, though; like as not I'll never know.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

The comment above was indeed the solution.
.vimrc now reads as below, probably I can remove some the earlier experiments.

```
set nohlsearch
set t_Co=0
highlight LineNr NONE
hi CursorLine NONE
hi Normal cterm=none ctermfg=none ctermbg=none
set t_TE=""
set t_TI=""
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw something similar today on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

- the cause is the vi package installed is vim-tiny, so a minimal version of vim

Installing the more complete version resolved the problem, e.g. doing

$ sudo apt install -y vim